# How to get data only outside the date range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get the ID which not doing transaction

Example I have data like this

| id | date | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 100 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | 200 |
| 1 | 2022-01-16 | 300 |
| 2 | 2022-01-17 | 400 |
| 3 | 2022-01-18 | 500 |
| 4 | 2022-01-19 | 600 |
| 5 | 2022-01-31 | 700 |

and I want to get only the id that not doing transaction between 2022-01-15 until 2022-01-20 and if any id doing transaction on or out of the date (e.g. id 1 and 2) I want exclude those id. That's mean I want the output is

| id | date | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2022-01-31 | 700 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NOT EXISTS to find records with a matching id, within the desired range, and exclude them:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   YourTable k
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * 
   FROM   YourTable ex
   WHERE  ex.id = k.id
   AND    ex.dateColumn >= '2022-01-15'
   AND    ex.dateColumn < '2022-01-21' -- Day AFTER end date

)
```

**Results:**

| id | datecolumn | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2022-01-31 | 700 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b23e4e72e364e186bded589f344bae0d)*